# apache not responding on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP to run localhost, I start apache & mysql like always and I receive no errors. It has been always working fine suddenly all projects that runs on wordpress keep loading for very long time then crashes and  get an error on the browser `apache not responding` with no errors showing up on xampp logs. All static sites (html) are working fine.
I made sure nothing conflicting with the port. I got Skype and IIS on different ports and also disabled them to make sure but I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: teamviewer also uses port 80. When all static files (html, css, js, ...) load over localhost and php files doesn't then s.th is wrong with php. Maybe a broken wordpress extension?

Comment: Can you run other PHP-files outside of Wordpress? Create a file: `info.php` with only the content: `<?php phpinfo();`. Does that one work?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes this does work.

Comment: @mirko911 i don't think so all my wordpress projects were working fine until suddenly this happened, if assumed there is a broken wordpress extension in one project, would this stop any other wordpress project from running ?

Comment: Try to disable all plugins on one of the sites (clear the `option_value` for the row that has the key: `active_plugins` in the `wp_options`  table in your database). Never hurts to try...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson tried it still same problem

Comment: to understand it correct: you have many wordpress installs on your XAMPP localhost and they all stopped working from out of nowhere? Have you updated anything? PHP Update / Wordpress Update / MySQL User or PW change?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, was one wrong line of code in a wp_query on one of the wordpress sites.
but this is the first time i encounter something like this, a development error that does not throw any wordpress errors or PHP ones, instead it breaks Apache on localhost. Well at least i have learned something new that all weird issues could be tracked back to one messed up line of code.